# How to dispose the Azure Sendgrid Client?

Tags: c#, azure, sendgrid

I am  using Azure Sendgrid for Sending Email. How to create the client to send Email. It has no Idisposable Interface.

```
   public async Task<string> SendEmailAsync(string EmailTo, string Username, string Subject, string PlainTextContent, string HtmlContent)
    {
        string apikey = Configuration.AzureSendgridSecretProvider.ApiKey;
        string responseStatus = "BadRequest";
        var query = "Email_" + EmailTo + ";" + "Username_" + Username + ";" + "VerficationCode_" + HtmlContent+ ";apikey" + apikey;
        var client = new SendGridClient(apikey);
        try
        {
            var msg = new SendGridMessage()
            {
                From = new EmailAddress(Configuration.AzureTableStorageSendGridProvider.EmailAddress, Configuration.AzureTableStorageSendGridProvider.EmailName),
                Subject = Subject,
                PlainTextContent = PlainTextContent,
                HtmlContent = HtmlContent
            };
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(EmailTo, Username));
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
            responseStatus = response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return responseStatus;
    }
```

1. Can we create single client to send all SMS (Singleton)
2. How to call the using{} for dispose the object once send successfully?
3. is it has memory leak while calling like above?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking if it has a memory leak? Why do you think it needs to be `IDisposable`?

Comment: I am using like above code. what is the best approach need to follow? I have to send concurrent SMS in my Application. whether it will be fine or not?

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Can we create single client to send all SMS (Singleton)

You could use [bulk email service](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Glossary/bulk_email_service.html) of sendgrid to send email communications to large lists of multiple recipients.

> 2.How to call the using{} for dispose the object once send successfully?

I decompiled the sendgrid client and found that it was dependent on HttpClient to handle the actual Http communication  between your workstation and their API.

The http client implements the IDisposable interface which dispose each http request while the **sendgrid client has no disposable instance**.

> 3.is it has memory leak while calling like above?

Over time the **sendgrid client calling the mail api** seems to be holding on to or **leaking memory.**

When you try to send out hundreds or thousands of emails, you can see memory usage build up.Whatever it is in the client that is holding on to it, never released the memory even days later and we had to reboot the server to clear it.

SendGrid client is dependent on Microsoft's HttpClient to handle the actual HTTP communication between your workstation and their API.

You could try to instantiate a single HttpClient and reusing it for each of your HTTP requests.

For more detail, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/658).